# Jquery Sortable drop event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a table, and want it to be drag-and-drop sortable. I'm able to move the rows around successfully. However, when I drop an item, I want it (for now) to show an alert.

My Jquery looks like this:

```
$('#debt_list').sortable({
    containerSelector: 'table',
    itemPath: '> tbody',
    itemSelector: 'tr',
    placeholder: '<tr class="placeholder"/>'

});

$("#debt_list").droppable({
    drop: function () {

        alert('dropped');
    }
});
```

Unfortunately, I can't get the alert to fire. There's no errors in the console. Just, no even fires when I move a row, and drop it on my table.

How can I get the drop event to fire (I'll be doing an ajax call, but for now, the alert is good. Maybe I can't use a table, and need to use a unordered list? Hopefully not.

The table is defined as:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive datatable" id="debt_list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Debt Name</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach (var m in Model.Debts.OrderBy(x => x.Description))
    {
      <tr class="index">
        <td>
          @m.Description - (@m.OpeningBalance.ToString("C2"))
        </td>
        <td class="text-right index">
          <i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </td>
      </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What versions of jquery and jquery ui are you using? Im not familar with `itemSelector` and `itemPath` but it works fine for me [in this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d160vLqm/51/) using the `items` option.

Comment: I'm using jquery 3.1.1 and UI version 1.12.1

Comment: [It's working for me here](https://jsfiddle.net/d160vLqm/53/) using those versions. Are you certain that the element exists on the page when you attempt to bind the handler? Do you have that code inside a dom ready function like  `$(function(){ ....});`?

Comment: Yes, I have a "$(function () {" surrounding all the code. Should that be there?

Comment: Yeah, it should. You're sure that there are no errors? And you're not loading jQuery multiple times anywhere are you?

Comment: In Chrome, I check the network tab, and only see "jquery-3.1.1.min.js" loaded once. Right after that, it does "jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js". Then further down, "jquery-sortable.js". Doesn't seem to be doing anything twice. My console screen shows no errors.

Comment: Hang on! I think you have kind of helped! Do I need to manually load "jquery-sortable.js"? It seems that might be part of jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js! Is that maybe the issue? If I comment out loading that, I get the popup! BUT, my entire table drags (not just a row). I think your query has helped.

Comment: FIXED! By doing what I just said. Thanks!